# Query a Table in Salesforce having 4 Million Records with 250 columns using Python/Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, salesforce

I need to pull a table ABC from Salesforce having 4Million records with 250 columns. I'm using python simple-salesforce API to do it, but if is running out of memory as I'm using a 8GB ram machine.

1. Is there any way to query this much large amount of records in salesforce using Pyspark, if so please suggest.
2. If there are any other approach also by using either Python or Pyspark, suggest them as well...

Answer (score 1):

Is there a chance you are using `query_all` from [simple_salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce)? If so, you might try `query_more` or `query_all_iter` instead so that your script does not attempt to load all into a single Python list.

[Simple Salesforce documentation here](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce).

Comment: Sorry to hear that. If you include some error output and code examples in your question, we may be able to help you further. Thanks!

Comment: I found some way... https://www.jitsejan.com/integrating-pyspark-with-salesforce.html . Thanks